# Get Groups for Specific User?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, groups, user

I want to retrieve all Groups a specific user is member of.
But it should include all Site Collections and in the best case also all Webapplications.
If there are two groups in different Site Collections with the same name, that they should be listed twice.

The System is a SP2013 on premise installation.

I think that the Groups property of a user only returns the ones of the SiteCollection? Right?

Is there a better way than iterating all SiteCollections->Webs and so forth?

Alex

Comment: Do you consider a user to be member of a SharePoint group, if he is member of an Active Directory group that is member of the group, or you need only the direct memberships?

Comment: Hi, i just need the direct membership. I want to know which groups a User with an Unique ID,Loginname,etc... is member of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **official and supported** solution is to iterate through all the web applications in the farm and then through all site collections in the given web application.
For example, using PowerShell:

```
$loginName = "domain\user"
Get-SPWebApplication | % { $_.Sites | % { $_.Url; $_.RootWeb.AllUsers | ? { $_.UserLogin -eq $loginName } | % { $_.Groups } | % { $_.Name } } }
```

Using an SQL query from the content DB (must be repeated on all content DBs in the farm!), the **unsupported** (!) way:

```
SELECT G.Title
FROM GroupMembership GM
INNER JOIN UserInfo U ON GM.MemberId = U.tp_ID
INNER JOIN Groups G ON GM.GroupId = G.ID
WHERE U.tp_Login = 'domain\user'
```

Comment: Puh, I really hoped there was a better solution for this, but thanks! I can only use the supported ways so I will iterate the webapps and sitecollections and so forth...

Comment: Ok, one question though: How would I do the same thing in SharePoint Online? Do I also need to iterate over all tentant site collections and webs?

Comment: I don't know any other official solution. The SQL query is for sure no way in SPO.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [SharePoint 2013 Permission Report: Check Access Rights for a Specific User](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Permission-2840f327). I think this report in PowerShell can help.

This are the parameters:

```
Generate-PermissionReport $Userid $WebAppURL $ReportPath
```

You can iterate web applications to call the report.
Hope it will be helpfully.